# Hyperbola ContourPlot missing input

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, syntax, geometry

I'm trying to plot a hyperbola using ContourPlot, but I can't understand what I'm missing on its call. The error says it's incorrect syntax, although I can't see any errors.

```
ContourPlot[8x^2-3y^2==24*22^2 , {x,-200,200} , {y,-200,200}]
```

The hyperbola's standard equation is

[image: (x^2/(22*sqrt(3))^2)-(y^2/(44*sqrt(2))^2)=1]

Thanks in advance!

~AR

Comment: works as expected in both version 9 and version 11.3.

Comment: Maybe you had some previous assignments to the symbols `x` or `y`. Evaluate that line (and that line only) with a fresh kernel.

Comment: That's actually weird, had the exact same expression but didn't work. Ended up copying what I wrote here and it worked... maybe there was an invisible character in-between the expression that didn't allow it to run